# "The API-version is not valid

Tags: powershell, httprequest, power-automate

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script, which will be run from a power-automate flow, and which in turn is supposed to call different power-automate flows via a Http request, the Url used here is generated by power-automate flow. My issue arise when I try to do

```
Invoke-Webrequest -Uri https://xxxx-xxx.westeurope.logic.azure.com:xxx/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01%26sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun%26sv=1.0%26sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx -Method POST -Body $PostParams
```

And when this is run, I get the error of

The Api-Version '2016-06-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-rmZzrBfsAvjCc' is not valid. It goes on to suggest some valid ones, which among them are '2016-06-01'.

I have tried removing %26sp, which also did not work. I've tried searching up any information regarding Api-version is not valid, but yielded no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, after quite a bit of back and forth and with an external answer I found out the URL had to be encoded before I could use it in my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
$request = 'https://put_here_your_uri'
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $request
```

And if you have header like bearer token add `-Headers $headers`

```
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'bearer HERE_BEARER_TOKEN'
}
```

Comment: This did not work, the exact same error message was displayed as before, so I think it has to do with the Uri that I'm using, that it must be fixed in some way shape or form